# VS code rust analyzer - no lint, autocomlete or hover

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust-analyzer

How to enable in VS Code  rust-analyzer

- hints
- linting
- auto complete?

here no contains function
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the correct folder to workspace and now it works just as a charm

Comment: I did the same; was trying to run a monorepo with a load of directories for notes and test projects. Needed to open the actual project root in a new VSC editor for rust-analyzer to take effect properly.